# How can I return value from setInterval function?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, settimeout, setinterval

I want to get status from async function but it always return status undefined and than it goes to function that contains  return status;

main.js

```
 let status = addData(firstname, lastname, age, sex);
 console.log(status);
```

data.js

```js
static async addData(firstname, lastname, age, sex) {
  try {

    let txdata = await data.dataentry(firstname, lastname, age, sex);

    let count = 0;
    let intervalId = setInterval(async() => {
      let status = await data.entryStatus(txdata);
      logger.info("status %o", status);


      if (status = true) {
        clearInterval(intervalId);
        return status;
      } else {
        count++;
        if (count > 4) {
          clearInterval(intervalId);
          throw createError();
        }
      }
    }, 500);

  } catch (err) {
    throw createError();
  }
}
```

Comment: You have an assignment, not condition check in **if** block

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard way to return result from async function is to use [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).
It is quite similar to described by Attila but you don't need a library to use it.

It works in all modern browsers and nodejs / iojs so if you don't care about Internet Explorer, it is the best option as I think.
If you need Internet Explorer, you may use shim.
"shim promise" in Google gives several options but I didn't try any.